# HTML Page Being Loaded Into DIV Via Navigation - Can I Directly Link To It?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using the code shown below to load a webpage into a DIV using the navigation menu. I found it elsewhere on this site on a closed post.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Website</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#mySidenav a').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var page = $(this).attr('href');
                $('#content').load(page);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="nav">
        <a href="page1.html">Page 1</a>
        <a href="page2.html">Page 2</a>
        <a href="page3.html">Page 3</a>
    </div>
    <div id="content">Use the menu to navigate website. </div>
</body>

</html>
```

It works perfectly and is exactly what I need, but my question is can I somehow link directly to this page from somewhere else, but somehow send the `pagex.html` in the URL also? If I just link directly to `pagex.html` I don't get the navigation page around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can with hash:

mydomain.com/#pagex.html

```
if (location.hash) {
  $('#content').load(location.hash.replace('#', ''));
}
```

Or with querystring:

mydomain.com/?url=pagex.html

```
if (location.search) {
  $('#content').load(location.search.replace('?url=', ''));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Where does that bit of code go? Sorry - I'm a script newbie.

Comment: Hi Charles - I have tried to use this code in multiple ways, but I don't seem to be able to get it to work - Are you able to assist please? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Charles - After many hours of frustration I got your suggested to code to work - Turns out I had to put it at the bottom of the page AFTER the menu code. Thanks for your help!